# How do I make a rule in firebase realtime database security rule so that only those users can write the data if they are in certain time slot?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Basically if I have a document in the collection which has a certain field, let's say, a start time and an end time. Now I want the user incoming write request to pass only if that user's time falls under that start time and end time. Also let's assume the user's uid is also not null (which means that the user is authenticated).

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow writing for authenticated users only, you can use the [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#realtime-database). For example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path/$sub_path": 
      ".write": "auth.uid != null
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, it’s not possible to validate writes on meeting a certain time slot, however, you may want to consider a function that would use one of the [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions) like `now`.
You can also submit a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) to add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks...this was helpful

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't up-vote your answer....as my reputation is too low.